# Tomcat service not running after installing XAMPP

Tags: tomcat, xampp, windows-7-x64

I have followed the following steps to install XAMPP 1.7.7 in Windows 7 Home(64-bit)

1. I downloaded the ZIP file instead of the the EXE file, and saved it to the "Downloads" folder.
2. Using WinRAR I extracted all contents within it.
3. After extracting the ZIP file, I moved the newly created "xampp" folder from "Downloads" to "C:\"
4. Next, I turned off the User Account Control (UAC).
5. Then, navigated to "C:\xampp" and created a shortcut to the Desktop.
6. Ran the new XAMPP Control Desktop shortcut and "Start"ed the ones for MySQL, Apache and Tomcat. For, MySQL, Apache I see a green "Running" indicator. However, for Tomcat NOTHING. The log shows that Tomcat has started on port 8080, but in reality it is not and I am not seeing green "Running" indicator.

When I open up Web Browser, and type in http://localhost I see the XAMPP splash screen. But, if I try with http://localhost:8080, it shows "unable to connect". If I go to Tomcat Status I see:

XAMPP Status
This page offers you one page to view all information about what's running and working, and what isn't working.

```
MySQL database                   ACTIVATED      
    PHP                          ACTIVATED      
    HTTPS (SSL)                  ACTIVATED      
    Common Gateway Interface (CGI)   ACTIVATED      
    Server Side Includes (SSI)   ACTIVATED      
    SMTP Service                   DEACTIVATED      
    FTP Service                DEACTIVATED      
    Tomcat Service                 DEACTIVATED
```

Why is Tomcat DEACTIVATED? I have tried to install XAMPP 1.7.7 with .EXE file and the same thing happens. How can I fix this?

Comment: This is because your JDK / Java runtime environment is not 32 bit version as like the xampp is 32 bit structure.

Step 1: Uninstall your xampp. Step 2: Uninstall your java and jdk.

Step 3: Install jdk-8u131-windows-i586.exe from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

step 4: Reinstall your xampp.

This will solve your problem.

Comment: In my case, "C:\xampp\tomcat\bin" contains "tomcat10.exe" but "C:\xampp\control.ini" references to "tomcat8.exe" in [BinaryNames] part. I ran notepad as administrator and changed that line to "Tomcat=tomcat10.exe" and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 13):

For some reason your xampp app  can't run the calatina_start batch file. Go to c:\xampp\tomcat\ press "catalina_start", it will start the batch file for you and then if you check the status on localhost again it will show you that tomcat service is activated and you can load localhost:8080. 
But i don't know the reason why it doesn't run with xampp automatically. Hope this helps. 
If you figure out something else, let me know.

Comment: In my case it works with Windows Vista, thanks

Comment: Thanks, it helps in Windows 7 as well. Voted your suggesstion :)

Comment: Thank you, your answer worked! But I can't help but wonder if there is a permanent solution or would I need to run bat files manually all the time?

Answer (score 5):

I found that there might be some mistake in the path for "catalina", because
in my case it worked directly after the installation and it says:
catalina home: xampp/tomcat
but when you stop all and you start again or even after reboot
the path for catalina home given in the black DOS window is: xampp/tmp/tomcat
and the message: "Path could not be found" 
I suppose, there is the main bug...

Regards
schubi

Comment: I had the same problem but found that XAMPP Control Panel start link had start folder set to ...\xampp\tmp
When I changed that to ...\xampp it worked as intended.

Comment: This is because your JDK / Java runtime environment is not 32 bit version as like the xampp is 32 bit structure.

Step 1: Uninstall your xampp. Step 2: Uninstall your java and jdk.

Step 3: Install jdk-8u131-windows-i586.exe from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

step 4: Reinstall your xampp.

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Java jdk installed on your PC first of all. Download a copy from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u25-download-346242.html) and re-run your xampp.