# XAMPP: tomcat doesn't start from control panel, starts only from bat

Tags: java, tomcat, xampp, tomcat7

I installed XAMPP and have trouble starting tomcat. Apache, MySQL, FileZilla start without problems when I click the "Start" button, while Tomcat writes `Attempting to start Tomcat service...` and seems to pass out - it doesn't start no matter how long I wait for it.

I can start it manually from `catalina_start.bat` though. But I really wish to find out what causes this problem and be able to start tomcat from control panel. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I think that problem is about port conflict, by default both Apache and Tomcat using port 8080, when you using XAMPP and start Apache first then Apache hold that port then you can not start Tomcat, you can start Tomcat via bat file my be because you already stopped the Apache. Also by default when you click on Start button of Tomcat on XAMPP, it will call to `catalina_start.bat` file.

Comment: But I don't stop Apache before manually starting catalina .bat file. The Apache still runs - on ports 80 and 443.

Comment: Your xampp may be broken some where, let's try to download a new one. It's so weird because from the xampp windows it can not call to run the catalina_start.bat file although you can do it by manual.

Comment: I downloaded and installed it several times, so I don't think that's the case... (

Comment: Did you get any detail error message? I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587803/tomcat-service-not-running-after-installing-xampp) has the same problem with yours

Comment: nope, no error message, unfortunatelly. Maybe I should wait longer for it. It really looks like it's searching for the bat files and can't find them. And I'm not sure how to fix it. I think the Start button has the wrong search directory coded into it somewhere.

Comment: Where did you installed your xampp? Let's try to reinstall it to another folder at root of drive like: C://xampp